# Display a menu prompt and save user selection description as a variable in powershell script

Tags: function, powershell, variables

Unfortunately not much of a Powershell guy.  Looking to accomplish the following:

```
Prompt the user with a list of choices: 
1 - gaming
2 - Home Ent
3 - Theatrical
4 - TV and Streaming
5 - VR
```

Then, given the users response (1-5), it saves the type as a variable (ie if they chose 3, then the variable ($projectType) gets saved as the ChoiceDescription of "Theatrical".

The rest of the script creates AD groups, a directory structure, and sets permissions. That part I have figured out, but the menu prompt is alluding me.

Been messing around with PromptForChoice but have been failing quite miserably.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: on advice of Vasil I know have this:

```
Function Get-ProjectType {
    $type=Read-Host "
    1 - gaming
    2 - Home Ent
    3 - Theatrical
    4 - TV and Streaming
    5 - VR
    Please choose Project Type"
    Switch ($type){
        1 {$projectType="Gaming"}
        2 {$projectType="Home Entertainment"}
        3 {$projectType="Theatrical"}
        4 {$projectType="TV & Streaming"}
        5 {$projectType="VR"}
    }
    return $projectType
}

#import the ActiveDirectory Module and define the parent folder path

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$path = "\\calamedia\edit\$ProjectType"
 $newProjectName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Name of Project"
 $newFolderFull = $path + $newProjectName
 Write-Output "New Folder will be: $NewProjectName"
 $confirm = Read-Host "Confirm? Y/N"
 If(($confirm) -ne "y")
 {
     # End
 }
 Else
 {}

 Write-Output "Create AD Groups"
$groupnameRW = "Shared.$newProjectName.RW"
$groupnameR = "Shared.$newProjectName.R"
New-AdGroup $groupNameRW -samAccountName $groupNameRW -GroupScope DomainLocal -path "OU=Projects,OU=Managed Groups,DC=createadvertising,DC=com"
New-AdGroup $groupNameR -samAccountName $groupNameR -GroupScope DomainLocal -path "OU=Projects,OU=Managed Groups,DC=createadvertising,DC=com"

# add the folder itself and remove inherited permissions

Write-Output "Add Folder.."
New-Item $newProjectName -ItemType Directory
Write-Output "Remove Inheritance.."
icacls $newFolderFull /inheritance:d
```

However it seems to now jump directly to the "Enter name of project:" prompt from later in the script and displays nothing for the function?

Comment: You can just use `Write-Host` and `$var = Read-Host`

Comment: I have a function that will make a decent looking menu in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691249/option-menu-in-powershell-continue-after-loop/48694405#48694405) answer. Also example code for how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

I see your code now, I have edit my code example in a way you can apply it.

You can use `Read-Host` to place some text and `Switch` to get the choose variable.

```
Function Get-ProjectType {
    $type=Read-Host "
    1 - gaming
    2 - Home Ent
    3 - Theatrical
    4 - TV and Streaming
    5 - VR
    Please choose"
    Switch ($type){
        1 {$choice="Gaming"}
        2 {$choice="Home Entertainment"}
        3 {$choice="Theatrical"}
        4 {$choice="TV & Streaming"}
        5 {$choice="VR"}
    }
    return $choice
}

$projectType=Get-ProjectType
```

And now `$projectType` contain the name of choice.

Comment: Giving this a try... copied and pasted it directly into my script but it seems to be skipping over this section completely and moving to the next now?

Comment: Adding my new code in original question with comments

Comment: You sir, are a hero.  Thank you